# BarcodeLib - Generate an ITF barcode with more than 14 characters

Tags: .net, barcode

I'm using BarcodeLib to generate barcodes, and I scanned this barcode from a real receipt :

[image: ITF encoded barcode with value '0888354615492903200123']

As you can see, my barcode is encoded using ITF. But for some reason the represented value is bigger than the 14 maximum characters allowed by ITF.
I'm trying to create my barcode like this :

```
Barcode barcode = new Barcode();
SKImage image = barcode.Encode(BarcodeStandard.Type.ITF14, receiptId, SKColors.Black, SKColors.White, 300, 50);
Stream imageStream = image.Encode().AsStream();
```

And obviously it throws me this error when I'm trying to pass the retrieved value :

```
Common.Utils.ErrorMiddleware[0]
      An exception occured processing request: /api/Demat/receipt/<receiptId>/pdf
      System.Exception: EITF14-1: Data length invalid. (Length must be 13 or 14)
         at BarcodeStandard.BarcodeCommon.Error(String errorMessage)
         at BarcodeLib.Symbologies.ITF14.Encode_ITF14()
         at BarcodeLib.Symbologies.ITF14.get_Encoded_Value()
         at BarcodeStandard.Barcode.GenerateBarcode(String rawData)
         at BarcodeStandard.Barcode.Encode()
         at BarcodeStandard.Barcode.Encode(Type iType)
         at BarcodeStandard.Barcode.Encode(Type iType, String stringToEncode)
```

Is there a way to recreate this barcode using ITF, without truncate my value? Or do I have to change the encoding type to get it work? (I already tested with Code128 and it's working, but I don't know if it's right)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution : ITF and ITF-14 are really different, because their encoding algorithm doesn't work the same way. In order to have a barcode encoded with ITF encoding, you need to use **Interleaved2Of5** type, like this :

```
Barcode barcode = new Barcode();
SKImage image = barcode.Encode(BarcodeStandard.Type.Interleaved2Of5, receiptId, SKColors.Black, SKColors.White, 300, 50);
Stream imageStream = image.Encode().AsStream();
```